# Поиск уязвимостей - это значит поиск ошибок в программе?

Tags: отладка, уязвимости

Допустим, поиск уязвимостей в браузерах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да. Но тех ошибок, которые можно использовать для получения доступа к системе жертвы.

То есть, через которые можно запихать в память браузера свой произвольный код и заставить его выполниться.

Comment: практически во всех толстых учебниках по веб в свое время писали о уязвимостях найденой у полей ввода (в случае криво написаной программы/сайта):

15; select * from balances (пример ввода)


вы можете догадатся что будет если программа подставит это в свой запрос который может выглядеть так:
'select e_mail from users where id = ' + <текст вытянутый из приложения>

Answer (score 4):

Не обязательно ошибок, в смысле неработающего, или неверно работающего кода. Возможно просто специфичных состояний программы, когда её поведение выходит за рамки, заложенные разработчиком / проектировщиком.

Опять же, не обязательно цель - выполнить свой код. Нанесение ущерба может быть связано с другими формами управления уязвимой средой. Например, отвлечение ресурсов, или создание возможности для другой уязвимости.

Но конечный итог использования любой уязвимости несомненно в злоупотреблении уязвимой системой без согласия законного пользователя.